# How to create stored procedure in clickhouse?

Tags: database, jdbc, clickhouse

Is there any concept like other DBMS **stored procedures** in *Clickhouse*?

I just want to save an statement with dynamic parameters in a file(or object) and call it. Like call stored procedures in mysql `call xxx(parameters)` and return the records. The user defined functions (UDF) in *clickhouse* is not applicable for me. I need a result set to crawl on it and use that in an application like JDBC in Java. We can use `SELECT * FROM table` statement on *clickhouse* over JDBC but we don't have any SP concept to call it on *clickhouse*.

Answer (score 3):

Save your query in a file - for example: `my_query.sql`

```
SELECT 
   toDate({start_date: String}) + number AS month
FROM numbers({days: UInt32});
```

The placeholders in curly braces are defined at query time using `--param_<name_of_parameter>`. For example:

```
./clickhouse client --param_start_date='2023-12-01' --param_days=31 < my_query.sql
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I need to call it from JDBC like a simple select. We can execute select to clickhouse in java but there is no SP concept to call it as well.

Comment: Have you tried a parameterized view? https://clickhouse.com/docs/knowledgebase/how_to_use_parametrised_views

Comment: It may help. But exist in `ClickHouse version 23.1+` while I use 22. Need to upgrade first and check if it works for my scenario.  Thanks.